# How do I merge a bugfix from a maintenance branch back to trunk in subversion

Tags: svn, merge

In the svn book ( http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html ), in the section on Common Branching Patterns, it says:

> The trunk is copied to a “release” branch. When the team thinks the
>   software is ready for release (say, a 1.0 release), /trunk might be
>   copied to /branches/1.0.
>
> Teams continue to work in parallel. One team begins rigorous testing
>   of the release branch, while another team continues new work (say, for
>   version 2.0) on /trunk. If bugs are discovered in either location,
>   **fixes are ported back and forth as necessary**. At some point, however,
>   even that process stops. The branch is “frozen” for final testing
>   right before a release.

(emphasis mine).  I'm assuming a maintenance branch is the same as a release branch..? (we need to keep one customer at a previous version while we develop their next version).

I'm pretty sure I shouldn't use `--reintegrate`, but I'm not quite sure how to do the merge in such a way that I don't mess up future merges.  Do I need to keep track of the revision ranges manually? ..or will subversion do it for me (I'm using version 1.7.6).

**[edit: more details]**

```
trunk> svn mkdir c
trunk> touch a.txt b.txt c\d.txt
trunk> svn add a.txt b.txt c\d.txt
trunk> svn ci -m "initial trunk"
...
Committed revision 9580.

trunk> svn copy .../trunk .../branches/branch1 -m "create maint branch"
Comitted revision 9581.

trunk> svn rm c\d.txt
trunk> svn ci -m "Fix bug-1."
Deleting       c\d.txt

Committed revision 9582.

branch1> svn merge .../trunk
--- Merging r9581 through r9582 into '.':
D    c\d.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r9581 through r9582 into '.':
 U   .

branch1> svn ci -m "Merged fix for bug-1 from trunk."
Deleting       c\d.txt
Committed revision 9583.

branch1> svn propget svn:mergeinfo .
/svntests/trunk:9581-9582

trunk> svn up
Updating '.':
At revision 9583.
```

**[original problem]**

```
trunk> svn merge .../branches/branch1
--- Merging r9581 through r9583 into '.':
   C c\d.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r9581 through r9583 into '.':
 U   .
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

**[fix from @JB Nizet]**

```
trunk> svn merge -c 9583 --record-only .../branch1
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r9583 into '.':
 U   .

trunk> svn propget svn:mergeinfo .
/svntests/branches/branch1:9583
```

then future merges from the maintenance branch will work (updating mergeinfo on trunk correctly) without creating conflicts:

```
trunk> svn merge .../branch1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A release branch is used to prepare the final steps of a release. A maintenance branch is used to fix bugs once a release has been done. They're both branches, and it's purely a semantic difference, but it's still a difference.

To merge your bug fix, you just make sure your working copy points to the trunk (the destination branch), and then merge from the maintenance branch (or a revision range of the maintenance branch if you don't want everything merged):

```
svn merge url_of_the_maintenance_branch
```

The next merge will remember that these revisions have already been merged to the trunk, and will skip them automatically.

Comment: I have merged bug fixes from trunk to the maintenance branch using that method, but when I try to do a merge from the maintenance branch back into trunk I get a significant number of tree conflicts for files that have been deleted on trunk (but not modified on the maintenance branch)..

Comment: Then you should not merge these bug fixes back to trunk, since they're in trunk already. Merge these specific revisions with `--record-only` to mark them as merged, so that subsequent merges of the whole branch ignores them.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question.. I'm not sure where I need to add the `--record-only`?

Comment: What I suggest is to merge revision 9583 (the revision created by the merge from trunk to branch) from branch to trunk, with the `--record-only` option. This means: *this revision comes from trunk, so there's no need to re-apply it to trunk, so we'll mark it as merged without actually merging it*. Once that is done, you can merge the whole branch to trunk, and the revision 9583 won't be merged because it's marked as already merged in the merge-info. And you will thus avoid the tree conflict.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question to reflect your answer (seems I'll have to wait some 13 hours before I can award the bounty..).